# Join 4 tables across 2 databases - Getting duplicates

Tags: sql, join, reporting-services

**Objective**: Pull report usage statistics from MS SSRS ReportServer database. Then, link to another table in a separate database (same server) to pull in employee names (Report Server only lists someone's Windows login name).

**Issue**: I have written a query that runs without errors, but I can confirm it's pulling in far too many records. I think this is because the employee file has multiple records per employee and there is not a unique column to go off of. I think it could do with the join but I have not been able to figure it out, so hoping someone can help.

**Table 1 - Catalog (ReportServer DB)**

| Type | ItemID | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Random unique sequence of numbers | Report Name A |
| 3 | Random unique sequence of numbers | Report Name G |

**Table 2 - ExecutionLogStorage (ReportServer DB)**
| TimeStart | TimeDate\aRetrieval| TimeProcessing | RowCount | ByteCount | UserName|ReportID|
|:--------- |:----------------:|:--------------:|:--------:| :--------:|:--------:|---------:|
| 2022-03-16 07:00:16:767| 11000| 500| 250| 150| Domain\UserName | Random sequence of numbers |

The only unique column on this table is a LogEntryId column (a number for each row).

**Table 3 - Users (ReportServer DB)**
| UserName|
|:----------------:|
| Domain\UserName |

UserName is unique (one row exists for each UserName)

**Table 4 - Employees (Custom DB)**
| WindowsLogIn|EmployeeName| Position|
|:--------- |:----------------:|---------:|
| Domain\UserName |John Smith | Director |
| Domain\UserName | Mary Allen| Manager |

**Current Query (resulting in erroneous counts (duplicated rows, much higher counts than expected)**

```
SELECT
   EmployeeName, 
   Position,
   sum(ExecCount) AS ExecCount,
   sum(UniqueReportCount) AS UniqueReportCount

FROM
   (SELECT
      RE.EmployeeName,
      RE.Position,
      COUNT(*) AS ExecCount,
      COUNT (DISTINCT RptName) AS UniqueReportCount

      FROM
       (SELECT
         EX.TimeStart, 
         CAT.Type,
         CAT.Name AS RptName,
         EX.TimeDataRetrieval,
         EX.TimeProcessing, 
         EX.TimeRendering,
         EX.ByteCount,
         Ex.[RowCount],
         EX.UserName AS LogUser,
         Users.UsernName,
         Employees.WindowsLogIn,
         Employees.EmployeeName,
         Employees.Position

         FROM [ReportServer].Catalog AS CAT
         INNER JOIN [ReportServer].[ExecutionLogStorage] AS EX ON CAT.ItemID = EX.Report.ID
         LEFT OUTER JOIN [ReportServer].[Users]. AS Users ON Users.UserName = EX.UserName
         LEFT OUTER JOIN [CustomDB].[Employees] AS Employees ON Users.User = Employees.WindowsLogIn collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
         
          WHERE Type = 2
          AND EX.TimeStart BETWEEN @DateFrom AND @DateTo
          ) AS RE
   
    GROUP BY
      EmployeeName,
      Position,
      RptName
    ) AS UserLog

GROUP BY EmployeeName, Position
ORDER BY ExecCount DESC
```

**Current Output**
Currently I'm getting the intended format in the report I built in SSRS. It's just the data that is duplicated. I have tried changing the Group By without much luck so I am wondering if it has to do with the last join? But how would I pull in the Employee Names from the Employees table if there are multiple records for each person on that table?

The format of the current output is like this:
| Employee Name | Position | Report Executions| Unique Reports|
|:------------- |:--------:|:----------------:| -------------:|
| John Smith | Director | 1000 | 50 |
| Mary Allen | Manager| 500| 10|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your duplicates are in `[CustomDB].[Employees]` then just select distinct values from this table.

So change this

```
 LEFT OUTER JOIN [CustomDB].[Employees] AS Employees ON Users.User = Employees.WindowsLogIn collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

to this

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT WindowsLogIn, EmployeeName, Position FROM [CustomDB].[Employees]) AS Employees ON Users.User = Employees.WindowsLogIn collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

Comment: I tried to update the portion of the query as follows: 1) moved the SELECT items for the employee table to the new subquery per your suggestion and 2) added in the new subquery. But I am getting errors: 
'LEFT OUTER JOIN [ReportServer].[Users]. AS Users ON Users.UserName = EX.UserName
WHERE TYPE = 2    **(ERROR)**                                                        
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT WindowsLogIn, EmployeeName, Position FROM [CustomDB].[Employees]) AS Employees ON **Error** Users.User = Employees.WindowsLogIn collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'

Comment: Apologies, I am a newbie and new to figuring out to format here. Is the issue that I need to move the WHERE clause somewhere else or add in a bracket? I have tried a few different scenarios but it's still throwing errors.

Comment: I noticed if I have [CustomDB].[Employees]) AS Employees then I am getting a ton of "could not be bound" errors. I did try to add aliases throughout the query but that did not help. Is there something else that can cause that?

Comment: If you original query was working, but was returning duplicates then all you needed to do was swap one line with the modified version I posted and it should work.

Comment: I must have messed up yesterday. It is working now with your modification Alan. Thank you so much for helping a newbie out!

Comment: No problem. Can you please mark the answer as accepted (the check mark to the left of the answer under the vote up/down buttons). This will help others find answers to similar questions.